# Node.js node-mysql2 insert Buffer as Blob directly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql2

What is the correct way to insert `Buffer` as `BLOB` just 1-to-1 without serializing to string/hex? Is it possible at all from Node.js?

At my backend I already have `Buffer`s with binary data and want to store them with minimum overheads using prepared statements. I'm getting `ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD errno:1366 Incorrect string value` error. It [looks like](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/1ff88900986276a437c80655dbee69e3375f1b9f/lib/packets/execute.js#L56) the library just assumes there is a valid utf8 string in a buffer.

Comment: @Vasan this is not a duplicate, I've seen the question, here I use mysql2 with prepared statements and the question is how to avoid turning buffers to hex strings before inserting to MySQL.

Comment: Yes, hence why I retracted my flag and added the tag.

Comment: After hours googling found a similar question but without an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933194/npm-mysql-sending-blob-data-to-a-mysql-server-as-a-binary-format

Comment: By the way, how do you conclude **the library just assumes there is a valid utf8 string in a buffer** from that line? It just checks if the given value is a Buffer.

Comment: Going forward and backward over callstack from this line. And I get an error from my tests, but it works fine with .toString() called on buffer. Haven't checked if it works correctly though. Also it is mentioned here at the bottom: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Prepared-Statements.md